# GCP loadbalancer not distributing traffic evenly/properly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have 3 instances attached to a gcp http loadbalancer. I have webservice running on all three of the instances. When I send requests , for example 3 request concurrently to loadbalancer, sometimes it routes all of the 3 requests to one instance, sometimes the loadbalancer routes the requests amongst the instances, but that is not even. What I mean by even is, when there is already load on a instance, still it would send request to that instance instead of sending to a instance which has no load. I would like to know how the loadbalancer distributes the traffic? And if there is any specific algorithm for distribution of traffic?

Loadbalancer has healthcheck on, which checks if the webservice is live, I have also tested with CPU usage and I get the same results.

Comment: In my limited experience I found the load balancer to be useful for addressing redundancy issues but not for speed or performance improvement.. We had high cpu usage  issue which was went down by large after adding second instance.. Also it was good to know we have a backup web server now.. I think the balancing acts in a reasonable way meaning it only occurs if benefits outweigh the costs..

Answer (score 1):

You can fin [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/about-capacity-optimization-with-global-lb#how_https_load_balancing_works) about how the traffic is load in a HTTP load balancer.  You should also have in mind the instances are physically in some cells, so might the instance itself isn't in use, but other instances from other projects in the same cell are using much resources and the cell is actually with less resources than the one where your instance is getting all the test traffic.